# Issue with logging in and authorized pages (session)

Tags: php

I'm using Wordpress to build my website. I'm creating a login system for schools to login to my system to view your information. I'm encountered problem when the user with authorized login, they can't get into the authorized page which is view-product page.

Please help.

Below is the login code.

```
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

// School code and password sent from Form
$myschoolcode = ($_POST['schoolcode']);
$mypassword = ($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT school_id FROM schools_info WHERE SchoolCode = '$myschoolcode' and Password = '$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$active = $row['active'];
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myschoolcode and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count == 1) {
session_register("myschoolcode");
$_SESSION['login_school'] = $myschoolcode;

header("location: ../view-products/");
}
else
{
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Your School Code or Password is incorrect, please reenter");
    history.back();
    </script>
    <?php
}

}
```

And below is the view-product page code.

```
session_start();
$school_check = $_SESSION['login_school'];

$ses_sql = mysql_query("SELECT SchoolCode FROM schools_info WHERE SchoolCode = '$school_check' ");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($ses_sql);

$login_session = $row['schoolcode'];

if(!isset($login_session))
{
header("location: ../enter-icas/");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I could -1 this I would. Your last problem is sessions, your first and foremost issue is that you are storing plain passwords? Not even a cruddy MD5? Not even a mt_rand()? Just plain? -> BIG PROBLEM! 2nd) Your taking user input data that your not even filtering, or validating, and instantly inserting that into a query and you think your safe because you use

> > '$please_inject_me_NOW'

You should use PDO. Take a look at the Php PDO manual.

Alright apart from my rant, from just looking at your view, I don't understand why you are doing another query from the $_SESSION variable?

All you have to do is set your session variable IF the credentials match which you have done.

Now at the top of each view page or in this view for example page all you have to do is :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])){ // If session variable 'LoggedIn' is not set then
        die("Access denied, you must <a href='index.php'><bold>Login</bold></a> to view this page!"); // Die with the message Access Denied, You must Login to view this page!
} else { // If session variable LoggedIn is set then yyyyaaay! Do your thing man.
  .........
}
```

Please read my comment though. YOU MUST use some sort of password protection = [Bcrypt](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) any one? Also don't forget PDO!

> > Edit 1

And don't forget to add session_start() before you implement the solution above (you probably already knew that though)

Comment: Thanks. I got the idea now. The system is on its earlier stages, the security module will be implement later on.

Comment: Alright, thats good, you had me scared for a moment! Every one starts some where so don't look down upon yourself or your efforts!! Good luck sir / Mam, and as always enjoy.